# ComboBox throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a ComboBox that I populate from a list. Once I have added the list to the ComboBox's items, I try to set the selected item to one of the items from the list. This item is definitely not null.

At this point, a NullReferenceException is thrown. However, the selected item has changed to the item I want it to be. If I re-run just the line of code assigning to SelectedItem, it doesn't throw another error.

The initial value of SelectedItem is null.

```
MyComboBox.Items.AddRange(mylist.Select(t => (object)t).ToArray());
try
{
    MyComboBox.SelectedItem = mylist[0]; //Checked - not null.
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

What is the NullReferenceException coming from?

**Solved:** The Exception was being thrown in the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: You add the items to `MyComboBOx` but reference the `SelectedItem` property of `SequenceSelecetor`.  Are these two different objects?

Comment: @Ek0nomik, I just missed that one

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code snippet you've provided. You'll need to give some more context. Perhaps you should turn on 'Break on Thrown Exceptions' to find out which LOC is causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks RJ. Unfortunately I am using VS Express 2010, which doesn't have that option. I have, however, found the source of the error.

Comment: what was the source of the error?

Comment: It was something in the Event that is called when the selected index is changed - I was trying to call a method on an object that happened to be null only in this first case.

Answer (score -1):

see if it works if you set `MyComboBox.SelectedItem = mylist[x]`. There is a good chance you aren't actually setting it to an item in the list.

Comment: The item it is being set to is definitely in the list, and is definitely not null.

Comment: Jay, he want's to set it to the initial value which is [0]. What you posted is what you would use if it was in a For statement (with x) to select desired value.

Comment: er sorry for not being clear, I was using x to represent an integer value since I did not know how many elements were in his list or which one he wanted it to default to.